Unable to capture a payment in PayPal v2 REST API
I am implementing @paypal/react-paypal-js
I am able to create an order hitting my backend server from createOrder callback in the PayPalButtons component to /api/order where I make the request on the server to the API at /v2/checkout/orders.
I get a response with two links one is where you are to redirect the user to approve their payment (payer-action). I go to that link in a new tab, login to a sandbox account and proceed to complete payment. It redirects to the redirect url.
I take the created orderID and past in in the JSON body in postman it hits another server endpoint I called /api/capture.
onApprove callback calls my server at /api/capture where I make a request to /v2/checkout/orders/{id}/capture where that orderID is put in the path.
The documentation says no request body is required, however doing so results in an error, so putting a request body works and I supply the same request body that is shown as required in the create orders documentation.
The result of submitting this request is PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED status.
But I thought redirecting to the payment link, where the payer "approves" of payment is where the payer action takes place, so why am I being asked this again? I am expecting a status of COMPLETED.

"however doing so results in an error" -- what is the complete error? And make sure the request's path is correct.

I am making the capture request to api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{id}/capture. I am using axios and passing null for the body. axios.post(captureUrl, null, { headers: {  Authorization: Bearer ${token}  } }). I had read to put [] but that doesnt work. I am getting the error UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE passing null and INVALID_REQUEST for passing []. Passing a JSON request body of  payment_source.paypal.experience_context results in PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED.

what are the complete errors. use an empty string or leave the body undefined

Empty string results in { name: INVALID_REQUEST, message: "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema." } Passing undefined results in { name: UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, message: 'The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.' }. Passing a JSON body with payment_source.paypal.experience.context does not result in an error, it results in a 200 OK, with payment_source being populated with my email address, but the status is still PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED, not COMPLETED.

complete errors will include a debug id. some combination of setting the Content-Type header to application/json and not setting data or setting an empty string or {} should work

I have tried all possible combinations. Nothing results in a status COMPLETED.

make a minimum example that reproduces and put it in your question, or don't use axios for the capture

I switched over to the old library to remember what the error was.  The error I get on capture says { "issue": "PAYEE_NOT_CONSENTED",
"description": "Payee does not have appropriate consent to allow the API caller to process this type of transaction on their behalf. Your current setup requires the 'payee' to provide a consent before this transaction can be processed successfully." } I feel this may be connected to my main issue. I never changed anything this error just came about out of nowhere.

Removing the payload in place of "" and also removing Axios worked. Thank you. Not sure whats wrong with Axios there. Confusing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
